# OctoberCMS filter Relation Widget based from currently selected record

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

The title says it all, but to give an example. I have a `Member` record and a `Group`. A member can have memberships in many groups and a group can have many members. (So that's many to many and I would have a pivot table for it.)

Now, each group has membership grades. E.g., (Free, Freemium, Premium, Super Premium). So the `membership_grade` shall belong to the pivot table, right? But here's the problem, not all groups share the same grades. Some might have **Free** and **Freemium** only, some might have all.

In the `fields.yaml` of the `Membership` pivot model, I defined the `membership_grades` as a *Relation Widget*, like this:

```
pivot[grade]:
  label: Membership Grade
  span: full
  type: relation
  nameFrom: name
```

And in its relationship in `Membership.php` like this:

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'grade' => [
        'Acme\Models\Grade',
    ]
];
```

Obviously, this will expose **ALL** grades, since I'm pulling data from the `Grade` model. What I want is to expose the grades that is just available on that group, not **all**.

What I've thought to do (but I didn't, because it seemed impossible) is to try to pull data from the `grades` relationship of the Group, but how am I suppose to do that? (Since `Relation` widget manages the relation of the Model, I cannot simply pull data from other sources just like that).

Also I've tried to do `scopes` but how am I suppose to pass the current Group I'm in? Since it is needed as the filter, like this:

```
// Membership.php

public $belongsTo = [
    'grade' => [
        'Acme\Models\Grade',
        'scope' => 'filteredIt'
     ],
     // added this relationship to try the scopes approach
     'group' => [
        'Acme\Models\Group'
     ]
];

// Grade.php

public function scopeFilteredIt($query, Membership $m) 
// yes, the second parameter in the scope will be the 
// current Membership model. I've tried it.
{
    // this won't work, since we want the overall relation filter;
    // an instance of Membership won't help.
    // this would work if I can find a way to pass the 
    // current Group (record) selected, and get its grades, then use it here.
    return $query->whereIn('id', $m->group->grades->pluck('id')->all());
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have one doubt , why `$m->group` will not work ? as you are mentioning that if you can able to pass `current selected group record and its grades` so i think .. that `group` record will be equal to `$m->group` record. OR am i missing something ... as i don't get that part `this won't work, since we want the overall relation filter;` if you are able to explain it in little more detail it will be helpful.

Comment: ok may be i got your problem as for creation time you don't have relation so , you won't get that `group` from `$m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have noticed some `post values` during `pivot model` ajax call.

When you `add new record` and when your pivot model opens `post values` are like this

```
Array (
    [_relation_field] => groups
    [_relation_extra_config] => W10=
    [foreign_id] => 1
    [_session_key] => VrSCoKQrSkIsZNGIju5QIqpdbS3AADoGQRHAsv1e
)
```

So good thing is that we can now get `foreign_id` as it will be your `selected group id`
and we **can use it** at **creation** time and `for update` time `you know` we have `relation so we use that`.

```
public function scopefilteredIt($query, Membership $m)
{
    // we are checking relation is there or not
    if($m->group) {
        // yes group is there we use it 
        return $query->whereIn('id', $m->group->grades->pluck('id')->all());
    }
    else {
        // seems new record then use foreign_id
        $foreign_id = post('foreign_id'); //<-this will be your selected group id
        if($foreign_id) { // <- double check if its there
            $group = Group::find($foreign_id);
            return $query->whereIn('id', $group->grades->pluck('id')->all());
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

please comment if you get any issue.

> to check post

```
public function scopefilteredIt($query, Membership $m)
{

    // will show flash message with post data array
    $post = print_r(post(), true);
    \Flash::success($post);

    // we are checking relation is there or not
    if($m->group) {
        // yes group is there we use it 
        return $query->whereIn('id', $m->group->grades->pluck('id')->all());
    }
    else {
        // seems new record then use foreign_id
        $foreign_id = post('foreign_id'); //<-this will be your selected group id
        if($foreign_id) { // <- double check if its there
            $group = Group::find($foreign_id);
            return $query->whereIn('id', $group->grades->pluck('id')->all());
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: hi, im not currently home, I will try this later. thank you for you answer :), btw, is this available in the docs?

Comment: hi, my `post()` is an empty array, any thoughts?

Comment: no its `not available to docs`, but `post` will be empty for first request but when it will `request for pivot model` at that time it will be filled. one trick to check it, update answer check it

Comment: also, update `Group::find`, shouldn't be `1`, it should be `$foreign_id`

Comment: i want to filter it immediately upon opening the backend form so the user won't be able to select.

Comment: ok updated answer check `flash message` logic to debug post data

Comment: dd post: `"""
Array\n
(\n
)\n
"""`

Comment: dd will not work as it will stop execution flow, as that scope will be called multiple times not a single time so use give solution for proper debug , other wise it will be always empty

Comment: flashed message was: `Array ()`

Comment: team-viewer ? my skype : hardik_satasiya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164970/discussion-between-wreigh-and-hardik-satasiya).

Comment: hi, sadly, it seems that `scope` doesnt work with `relation` i've tried it with `recordfinder` and it's working. thank you for your effort!